# React native: editar parte superior de pantalla android

Tags: android, react-native, style, styled-components

estoy trabajando un proyecto con react native y uso un celular android para ver mis cambios, quiero agregar un fondo blanco a la pantalla completa, pero tengo una vista donde la parte superior del teléfono no toma los cambios (sección azul de la imagen), alguien sabe que podría funcionar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿ Te refieres a que no te funciona el componente nativo StatusBar que sirve para personalizarla ?

[StatusBar - React Native Doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar)

Comment: Gracias! justo eso estaba buscando